# Get OpenUDID of a device through mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, ios6, udid

I am planning to use [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) for one of my projects.

I have a couple of questions regarding it:

1. Can I use it only for for iOs or can it be used on Windows and Android platforms also?
2. I also want to track it when a user click on my app link on web browser. Is it possible, if I run some javascript in customer's browser to get OpenUDID id ? I mean do they have a javaScript version or any other version which I can use in mobile browser to get openUDID ?

Comment: Hello this is very old question but I require same answer. How to get UDID with link click from any kind of mobile browser?